# Запрос информации из url. Python

Tags: python

Прошу помочь: необходимо написать функцию, которая по ID валюты возвращает ее название на русском языке
Данные о https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js

```
import requests 
def currency_name(ID):
    url = ('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
    response = requests.get(url).json()['Valute']
    name = response[ID]
    return name 
print(currency_name(ID = 'R01700J'))
```

Моя нерабочая функция

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Почему нерабочая? Что происходит вместо работы?

Comment: name = filter(lambda z: z['ID'] == ID, [x for _, x in response.items()]).__next__()['Name']

Comment: name, *_ = (x['Name'] for _, x in response.items() if x['ID'] == ID)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

def get_currency_name_in_russian(currency_id):
  response = requests.get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js')
  data = response.json()
  return data['Valute'][currency_id]['Name']

currency_name = get_currency_name_in_russian('USD')
print(currency_name)
```

Comment: Добрый вечер! Замечательный код, однако работает только если на вход берет CharCode, по ID выходит ошибка что идентификатор не обозначен. Например, KeyError: 'R01020A'